# Nursing in the bathroom

Tags: halacha, food, women, bathroom, baby-infant

Per [Food in bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/food-in-bathroom) it is forbidden to eat in the bathroom. Can a lady nurse in the bathroom or is it considered like eating in the bathroom? (sources)

Comment: Is the nursing infant bound by the mitzvot?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, normally we don't allow someone to physically cause even an infant to violate _halacha_ (AFAIK; but consult your rabbi for practical guidance).

Comment: Consider the leniencies provided in this answer (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2048/5), as well as the importance of feeding a hungry infant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rav Aharon Yehuda HaLevi Grossman (V'Darashta VChakarta 4:42:7) permitted nursing in a bathroom particularly  in a case where doing so would allow for proper modest behavior.

[Source](http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/VDarashta-VChakarta-Feeding-Your-Baby-In-A-Bathroom/3224)

Comment: If there was no problem with modesty, is it still OK?

Comment: He brings a number of other reasons to be lenient besides modesty but he doesn't rule explicitly in that case. See the link.

Comment: The Ben Ish Ḥai mentions an opinion (I had thought it was his own, but apparently he only held it can be relied upon in She'ath HaDeḥak - http://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/ben-ish-hai; http://www.yoatzot.org/question.php?id=7552) that a nursing mother's breasts are considered like her hands and face (normally exposed), and that one can recite Shema' in front of her.

Comment: Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky permits it but if possible to avoid. See http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48356&st=&pgnum=22&hilite=

Answer (score 3):

So far, the only source I have seen for not eating in the bathroom  is the B'er Heitev ([OC 3:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=12)).  He extends this law as a kol shekein ("even more so") from talking.  I am assuming they are forbidden for the same reason- it is improper.  In line with that reasoning is why women did speak in a bathroom- otherwise there could be a breach in modesty.

I would think an infant has a different standard than an adult (do you stop feeding your child if *he* is expelling waste?), especially considering the following regarding talking (from R' Sheinberg):

While actually expelling waste (nifne): forbidden except for a great need

While on the toilet: permitted for a need (l'tzurach)

Finished expelling waste: permitted

While we cannot apply that directly to eating since that is worse (the kol shekain), it can certainly be used as a snif l'hakel (element to consider toward ruling leniently).