# How has toilets that flush changed halacha?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, bathroom

I was learning סימן מג in the שולחן ערוך and the משנה ברורה about wearing Tefilin in indoor and outdoor bathrooms. It mentioned that in a בית כיסא you would have the remnants of human waste, which would cause problems bringing something so holy as Tefilin.

If we have flushing toilets, do the same prohibitions apply?

Comment: Sources:
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13068&pgNum=82 , 
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20757&pgNum=29

Comment: Dup? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/what-is-the-halachic-status-of-todays-modern-bathrooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we apply the principle found in the first chapter of shabbos (bavli) and quoted in Rambam hilchos krias shema chapter 4(?) (will edit later for better citations, God willing), that is "בית הכסא אף על פי שאין שם צואה ומרחץ אף על פי שאין שם אדם"