# Are images of prophets permitted in bathrooms?

Tags: halacha, bathroom, pictures

Gentile here, so forgive my lack of knowledge.

There are pro-Jewish posters being placed in bathrooms at my workplace which contain an image of Moses (think Moses with the two tablets). The posters advocate for Jews and connect employees with Jewish resource groups at work. These posters are placed immediately next to toilets. I was surprised, but saw that some of the author names appear to be Jewish. Is the placement of such posters permitted?

Comment: Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99704/27180

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here!

Comment: We don't have images of any prophets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your sensitivity. In Judaism, pictures or photographs, even of the most righteous of people, have no sanctity whatsoever and as such there is no reason why they couldn't be placed near the toilets, although it could be debated that it is of poor taste. The only problem would be if the picture also has words of the Scriptures, on them, as could be the case in a drawing of Mozes, as those words do have sanctity and should not be brought into toilets.

Comment: Thank you for educating me. There was what appeared to be Hebrew on the "tablets" portion of the image. I'll see if I can find the image or take a photo of that portion.

Comment: Thank you. If it is the painting of Rembrandt, depicting Moses breaking the tablets, the Hebrew on that is indeed some actual words of the Scriptures. Even then, the Name of G'd (which would be the main prohibition) isn't written there, and them being written purely for art's sake and not for any holy purpose, I'm inclined to say that it is not forbidden, but definitely not of good taste.

Comment: Can I clarify something? In your original question you write that they are placed "in bathrooms" and "immediate next to toilets". With that last phrase, do you mean that they are in the same room/cubicle as the actual toilet pots, or next to the cubicles, i.e. in the areas where one washes ones hands?

Comment: The posters were in the same cubicle/stall as the toilets and directly above urinals. Here's the text on the tablets: https://imgur.com/a/94297Fx Since that's probably unreadable, based on what you're saying it would seem such image placement would be at worst considered in bad taste but permitted. After complaints at work, new posters were made where the image was replaced with the Star of David. Thanks again for educating me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts in having them removed. The text on the tablets, as posted by you, are indeed the actual words of the ten commandments. Of the last 9, they depict the first two words of each. Of the first one, it only says the first word. Ostensibly this is because the second word of that commandment is The Name of G'd, and the painter had the decency not to write that. It would have been uncomfortable to use the urinals with that image in front of me. Not that urinating in front of the Star of David shows much sensitivity either! Pity they weren't placed on the side! TY