# Can I keep a siddur in my wallet?

Tags: clothing, prayer-book

Many people have small siddurs that they use for Mincha and Marriv which they keep in their wallets. I happen to keep my wallet in my back pocket. If I pick up a siddur like this, am I able to keep it in my wallet (which is in my back pocket)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bringing wallet with benscher into bathroom](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/bringing-wallet-with-benscher-into-bathroom)

Comment: @Daniel I hear what you're saying about my question being a duplicate but the point that this question is focusing on is the fact that if I keep the siddur in my wallet in my back pocket I will be sitting on the siddur; a little different than the bathroom case

Comment: good question. probably better to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rav David Law, which now is the Rav Rashi of Israel, no.

His source is in Berachot (18a) which says that someone who brings bones or a Sefer Torah from place to place on his animal should not sit on them even if they are in a container (דקסיא) because it is disrespectful to the bones,the Sefer Torah and, by implication, the siddur.

source: [here](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/shut2.asp?id=904) and [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=11271)

Comment: I don't follow the implication: a Torah clearly is on a higher level than a siddur. There is no valid kal vachomer here.

Comment: DoubleAA: Perhaps because there are numerous passages from scripture that are integrated into Jewish prayer that a siddur is thus an abridged Chumash?

Comment: We learn laws of what you can do with a siddur, from what you can do with loose Torah scrolls. They aren't really different things in halacha.
This only applies if the wallet is in your back pocket though.