# Is it halachically ok to put up a printed copy of the Shema?

Tags: halacha, shema

Obviously printing out a copy of the Shema would not be acceptable for a mezuzah etc - but suppose I wanted to print out a copy of the shema in Hebrew (either a photocopy of a scroll or just a digital copy). Could I do that and put it on my desk at work, or on the wall in my living room in a frame? Is there any halacha to prohibit this?

Comment: I think there is a discussion somewhere (I think mishna berura in hilchos tefilla) about having printings of lamnatzeiach where the chazan davens. The possible problem is the names of God becoming erased due to wax of the candles there. Is there a risk that God's name will be erased?

Comment: @MosheSteinberg that's a good point, maybe it's a reason not to put it in direct sunlight from a window to avoid the paper being bleached. But otherwise in a frame I don't think that would be a risk?

Comment: Rav Kasher ז"ל used to run a Shma Yisroel movement and he would mail out  a poster with the first paragraph of Shma on faux-parchment to whoever asked. (Circa 1960-1980)

Comment: I didn't vote to close. But, if the concern in your question is based on the possibility that G-d's name MIGHT be erased, then see my related question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83999/5275. Offhand, your concern, here, seems the same as there. Otherwise, please refine your question so we can understand why you think there's a problem.